# Need an example of sqlite with Monodroid

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android

Can anyone point me to an example of using sqlite with Monodroid? I've been unable to find even one.

Comment: If you need tips on working with SQLite I also wrote a blog post here: http://www.elucidsoft.com/blog/2011/12/31/mono-android-working-with-sqlite/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I obviously need to add a SQLite demo to the ApiDemo sample.

Since I don't know when that'll happen, here's the quick and dirty version:

However, to use the following code you *must* be targeting Android 2.2 or later to use Mono.Data.Sqlite.  If you need to target an earlier Android version, you should look into a fully managed replacement, such as [managed-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/managed-sqlite/).

Furthermore, this example is using [Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=N:Mono.Data.Sqlite), which is included in the MonoDroid SDK.

First, edit your project assembly references and add a reference for `Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll` and `System.Data.dll`.

Second, within your source code, add:

```
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
```

Finally, use ye normal ADO.NET code:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine (
        Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
        "items.db3");
bool exists = File.Exists (dbPath);
if (!exists)
    SqliteConnection.CreateFile (dbPath);
var connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath);
connection.Open ();
if (!exists) {
    // This is the first time the app has run and/or that we need the DB.
    // Copy a "template" DB from your assets, or programmatically create one.
    var commands = new[]{
        "CREATE TABLE [Items] (Key ntext, Value ntext);",
        "INSERT INTO [Items] ([Key], [Value]) VALUES ('sample', 'text')"
    };
    foreach (var command in commands) {
        using (var c = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
            c.CommandText = command;
            c.ExecuteNonQuery ();
        }
    }
}
// use `connection`...
// here, we'll just append the contents to a TextView
using (var contents = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
    contents.CommandText = "SELECT [Key], [Value] from [Items]";
    var r = contents.ExecuteReader ();
    while (r.Read ())
        MyTextView.Text += string.Format ("\n\tKey={0}; Value={1}",
                r ["Key"].ToString (), r ["Value"].ToString ());
}
connection.Close ();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the missing link for me.

Comment: System.IO is not exists in Mono For android.. How can we use Mono for Android type of applications ?

Comment: It'd be a good idea to wrap the use of `connection` in a `using` block too, to guard against fair-weather programming :)