# MonoDroid Data Storage

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am very new to android development so pardon my ignorance.  I am simply trying to figure out how to use SQLite in my MonoDroid app but every tutorial I find references Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll which I do not have.  They say it is supposed to be in the monodroid SDK, but I cannot find it anywhere.  I am still using the evaluation version of mono.  Is this dll only available in the full versions or something?  All I have available in the Add Reference .Net is:

Mono.Android

Mono.Android.GoogleMaps

Mono.Cairo

Mono.CompilerServices.SymbolWriter

Mono.Data.Tds

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938867/need-an-example-of-sqlite-with-monodroid) as my instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be called System.Data.SQLite.  Unfortunately, the assembly name is different than the filename.

Comment: You're a genius.  I added System.Data.SQLite as a reference but it shows up under my references as Mono.Data.SQLite.  I can now add it with a using statement.  Thank You!