# How many ways to share data among activities in monodroid?

Tags: xamarin.android

I need to share some sensitive data among `activities`.
I have two `EditText` which are basically `username` and `password`
I am consuming a webservice which on the base of provided username and password return some user info (`DataType:String`). Like `userid`,`useremail` `etc..` which is basically in CSV format
I need these piece of information throughout my application.But i can't figure out which is the better way.

-- One way i could found out so far is to use [sqlite with MonoAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945737/1224003)
-- Other way i found out is using [Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data/4208947#4208947)
I just started to learn android today , but i want to know if there are some other ways to share data ?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, a global `Application` class and the database are two good ways to share application-wide data. One thing to be careful with is that your Application class could be recycled when the app is in the background, so you would lose any data that hasn't been persisted to something more permanent.

In addition to the database, you can also persist data down to the filesystem as well. [This recipe](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Recipes/Network/Web_Requests/Download_a_File) from Xamarin has an example of writing directly to a file. Most of the classes you'll need to do file access are found in the `System.IO` namespace. Mono for Android also supports [isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx), which provides a higher level API for reading and writing files.

If you simply need to pass data directly between activities, you can do so by adding it as an extra to the intent. [This recipe](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/Fundamentals/Activity/Pass_Data_between_Activity) explains how to do that.

If you want to wrap up access to a particular resource in a more managed fashion that can be accessed by either other parts of your application or even external applications, you can look into implementing a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Android itself provides several built-in content providers for resources like contacts and media, if you need an example of what it's like to use one. [This recipe](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/Data/ContentProviders/Read_Contacts) explains how to read from the contacts provider.