# sqlite-net and sqlite3.dll

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monocross

I am a bit confused about the sqlite3.dll in Mono. 
I just wonder have Mono for Android and MonoTouch already provided the unmanaged binary of the native C sqlite3 by default?

So I can do this in my code already with zero dependency?

[DllImport("sqlite3", EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Result Open ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename, out IntPtr db);

Or I need to add something before I can use above code?

Comment: Why are you concerned about dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that there is no extra coding or dependencies. 
SQLite-net just works like a charm on MonoDroid.

Either Android or MonoDroid already provides native sqlite3 C++ library.

Answer (score 1):

For MonoTouch it is iOS who provides the native sqlite3 library, so you should be able to invoke the native methods as you suggested.

For Mono for Android I do not know.

**Update**

For Mono for Android this seems like it would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4945737/183422

Comment: I guess so since the guy who made sqlite-net originally targeted iOS. For MonoDroid, do I need to add something on top, I don't know.