# FileNotFoundException when using SQLite-net-pcl

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

After adding SQLite-net.dll and using it, this error message is displayed.
Visual Studio 2017 is in use as IDE.

> Error     Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SQLite-net,
>   Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'SQLite-net.dll'
>
> at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver) TimeLogger.Android

I have tried various SQLite versions and various Android API levels but without success.

The Android packages are like those versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <packages>   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />  
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition" version="25.4.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />   
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="25.4.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid71" />  
<package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.4.0.280" targetFramework="monoandroid71" /> </packages>
```

SQLite-net-pcl refers to 1.3.0.

Can anyone provider a hint?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938867/need-an-example-of-sqlite-with-monodroid) might be of use.

Comment: That are other packages as far as seen.

Comment: [I found this for you, please take a look.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68974/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-assembly-system-drawing)

Comment: Nevermind - already solved

Comment: Perhaps another issue - had never a problem with System.Drawing. (In the past, I was already forced to manually delete the packages content (out of Xamarin scope).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously, the Xamarin cross platform solution was created with a shared project.
When creating a Xamarin cross platform solution with a portable project, this issue is not caused anymore.